# DrRacket finding themaximum and minimum is a set of 5 Numbers

Tags: racket

I'm very new to racket and I was trying to find the maximum and minimum values of a 5 numbers set and return them as a list.
I was planing on doing it using one function for finding the maximum and one function for finding the minimum and put the result in a list.(as can be seem in the code below)but I keep on getting errors and I can't seem to understand what's wrong.and help would be appreciated.

```
#lang pl
( : min&max : Number Number Number Number Number -> (Listof Number))
 (define (min&max x y z w v) 
 (define newlist '(x y z w v))
  (list (maxOf newlist) (minOf newlist)))



   ( : maxOf : (Listof Number) -> Number)
     (define (maxOf list)
    (cond
        ((null? list) (error "empty list"))
        ((null? (rest list)) (first list))
        (else (cond
                ((> (first list) (maxOf (rest list))) (first list))
                (else (maxOf (rest list)))))))


  ( : minOf : (Listof Number) -> Number)
   (define (minOf list)
    (cond
        ((null? list) (error "empty list"))
        ((null? (rest list)) (first list))
        (else (cond
                ((< (first list) (minOf (rest list))) (first list))
                (else (minOf (rest list)))))))
```

the errors I'm getting are:

```
Type Checker: type mismatch
expected: (Listof Number)
 given: (List 'x 'y 'z 'w 'v) in: newlist
Type Checker: type mismatch
    expected: (Listof Number)
 given: (List 'x 'y 'z 'w 'v) in: newlist
Type Checker: type mismatch
 expected: (Listof Number)
 given: (List Number Number) in: (list (maxOf newlist) (minOf newlist))
  Type Checker: could not apply function;
  wrong number of arguments provided
 expected at least: 2
 given: 1 in: (error "empty list")
  Type Checker: type mismatch
 expected: Symbol
 given: String in: "empty list"
  Type Checker: could not apply function;
 wrong number of arguments provided
  expected at least: 2
 given: 1 in: (error "empty list")
   Type Checker: type mismatch
 expected: Symbol
 given: String in: "empty list"
  Type Checker: Summary: 7 errors encountered in:
 newlist
 newlist
 (list (maxOf newlist) (minOf newlist))
(error "empty list")
"empty list"
(error "empty list")
"empty list"
```

> 

I was trying to put all the 5 numbers I get inside a list and call it newlist,that's what the (define newlist '(x y z w v)) was for
but I keep on getting errors for it.
plus I keep on getting errors for the (list (maxOf newlist) (minOf newlist)))

that was meant to put the max and min value inside one list and return it
and for the (error "empty list"))

Comment: My suggestion... go step by step... Make fn to find max of 2, then find max of 3 by making it recursive like the first answer does.

Comment: @TylerNichols Add your solution as a separate answer - you need some votes!

Comment: Can you show us how you are calling your functions? I'm guessing those errors are because you've defined your functions to take a list of Numbers, however you are calling them with a list of symbols like this: (minOf (list 'x 'y 'z 'w 'v)) instead of (minOf (list 5 3 8 1 9 0))

Answer (score 1):

Write a function `max2` that finds the maximum of 2 numbers, then the maximum of 5 numbers can be computed as

```
(max2 a (max2 b (max2 c (max2 d e)))).
```